# In NativeScript on Android, how do I prevent a SearchBar from gaining focus on page load?

Tags: nativescript

I have a SeachBar inside a ScrollView. In iOS all is good. On Android the ScrollView automatically scrolls to the SearchBar, adds focus to it and displays the soft keyboard. I can hide the softkeyboard by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` as an activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file but I can't work out how to prevent the focus (and hence the auto scroll). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you find out how can we fix this problem ?
Every time that i have a searchBar in a view, it is gaining focus and showing softkeyboard, i don't know how i can fix this :-s

Answer (score 14):

Using **Angular2**:

app/my.component.html

```
<StackLayout (loaded)="onSearchLayoutLoaded($event)">
    <SearchBar hint="search here" (loaded)="onSearchBarLoaded($event)">
    </SearchBar>
</StackLayout>
```

app/my.component.ts

```
    onSearchLayoutLoaded(event) {
        if (event.object.android) {
            event.object.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }
    }

    onSearchBarLoaded(event) {
        if (event.object.android) {
            event.object.android.clearFocus();
        }
    }
```

This eliminates unnecessarily having to use [template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars).

Comment: i tried it, but the focus still on the searchbar :/

Comment: Worked for me even in Angular 9

Answer (score 8):

For Android you need to do a couple of things. If you were using a native Android layout, lets say `LinerLayout` you would set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and that should work for most use cases. So with NativeScript you're going to use the associated method on the parent of your *SearchBar* and then call `clearFocus() on the searchbar.

#### Example

```
function removeSearchFocus() {
    // get the parent of the searchbar
    var parent = page.getViewById('parentLayout');
    var searchBar = page.getViewById('mySearchBar');
    if (parent.android) {
        parent.android.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        parent.android.setFocusable(true);
        searchBar.android.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

Then attach this function to one of the page navigation event, or dump the important pieces into a current page event you might already have in your app. Just assign the parent an ID and the *SearchBar* so you can get it by the ID and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `endEditing` to the page loaded or loading event?

```
searchBar = page.getViewById('your-searchbar');
searchBar.ios.endEditing(true);
```

or set focus to another element, where you want the focus to be, e.g.

```
somethingElse = page.getViewById('your-top-bar');
somethingElse.focus();
```